# How do i get noise to work in basil.js?

Tags: adobe-indesign, noise, basil.js

I dont manage to make b.noise work in basil.js. I allways get the error "ReferenceError: Uint8Array does not have a constructor". What am I doing wrong?

```
function draw() {  

var xoff = 0.0;
var xincrement = 0.01;

xoff += xincrement;
var n = b.noise(xoff);
b.println(n); 

}

b.go();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just closed this bug, so your code will be valid. The fix is already up on github. It will be included in the next release, which will be very soon.

Answer (score 0):

nothing! this is a bug in basil.js :( sorry! i've submitted the bug.
https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/issues/17